# Create "short cut" aware graph in Python

Tags: python, networkx, directed-acyclic-graphs

Assume we have these sequences:

```
A->X->Y->Z
B->Y->Z
C->Y->Z
D->X->Z
```

I would like to create a graph like:

```
    C
    |
A-X-Y-Z
  | |
  D B
```

In the sequence D-X-Z there is a short cut. My goal is to create a directed acyclic graph by eliminating these short-cuts and vice versa, expand existing edges when encountering expanded paths (e.g.: X-Z with X-Y-Z).

My approach so far was to create a directed graph with Networkx but this does not solve the problem because I could not find a way to eliminate short circuits (it is a big graph with hundreds of thousands of nodes).

Any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: "In the sequence D-X-Z there is a short circuit." What exactly does this mean? Is the output that you show correct or not? do you want an edge connecting X to Z directly? If not, why not?

Comment: @Karl this means that there are nodes forming a loop (see the images in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73887397/16343464))

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I do not want a direct X-Z edge. I want to keep the longer path.

Comment: A DAG is normally allowed to contain joins, though. Having X->Y, Y->Z and X->Z doesn't create a *cycle*.

Answer (score 0):

You can set up the graph:

```
import networkx as nx

text = '''
A-X-Y-Z
B-Y-Z
C-Y-Z
D-X-Z
'''

G = nx.Graph()

for s in text.strip().split('\n'):
    l = s.split('-')
    G.add_edges_from(zip(l,l[1:]))
```

[image: graph with cycles]

Then use [`find_cycles`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.cycles.find_cycle.html) and [`remove_edge`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/classes/generated/networkx.Graph.remove_edge.html) repeatedly to identify and remove edges that form cycles:

```
while True:
    try:
        c = nx.find_cycle(G)
        print(f'found cycle: {c}')
        G.remove_edge(*c[0])
    except nx.NetworkXNoCycle:
        break
```

[image: graph without cycles]

Comment: Thank you for your hint. This is something that could solve the problem. However, I noticed that the X-Y-Z order is not preserved in the final graph.

Comment: Is the graph directed or not? If undirected there shouldn't be an "order", if directed then the nodes are not forming a cycle (you would need a Z->X edge for example)

Comment: The graph is directed and yes, you are right, it is not a cycle if DAG. But I need to keep the longer path. I need to edit the question though. Thx.